# How can I only plot hours and minutes in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following data structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2015-02-02 14:19:00","2015-02-02 14:22:00","2015-02-17 14:57:00","2015-02-17 14:58:59"],"Occurrence":[1,0,1,1]})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```

I want to plot the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Occurrence",  data=df)
```

And I get this:

[image]

I only want the hours and minutes to be shown on the x axis (the date of the day is unnecessary). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `matplotlib`'s `Dateformatter`. Updated code and plot below. I did notice that the `Date` column you posted had dates on 2nd and 17th. I changed those to show everything on the 2nd. Otherwise, there would be too many entries. Hope this helps...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2015-02-02 10:19:00","2015-02-02 12:22:00","2015-02-02 14:57:00","2015-02-02 16:58:59"],"Occurrence":[1,0,1,1]})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

ax = sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Occurrence",  data=df)

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=2))
# set formatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

**Output Plot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would want to convert your ['Date'] column to only include time information, im not sure if you want the data to be ordered by date or not but that should just show time information on the X-axis:

```
df['Date'].dt.time
```